# which build in a travis matrix build is used for gh_page provider

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages

When I have a travis matrix build with a spec like this:

```yaml
matrix:
  include:
    - os: osx
      rust: stable
    - os: linux
    rust: stable
  allow_failures:
    - os: osx
```

and I use the deploy provider to upload an html book generated during the build:

```yaml
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip-cleanup: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_PAGES_TOKEN
  local-dir: target/html
  keep-history: false
  on:
    branch: master
```

Which build output is that gh_pages provider running on?

Answer (score 0):

From experimentation, it seems that the deploy: gh_pages provided is run on the last build in my matrix, in the example above: linux.

I am unsure if failure_allowed on the other builds (possibly combined with fast_fail) could change that though.

i.e.If the last one is allowed to fail (and it does) then I think the deployer will not run, even if overall the build has "succeeded" and is green.